# Bash script in cron not sending e-mail to provided e-mail address in script

Tags: bash, email, cron, postfix-mta

i have small bash script, it is working when executed from command line.
I get e-mail from alerts@xyz.one to mailbox bob.bok@example.com

```
#!/bin/bash

while read LINE
do
        if curl --insecure -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" "${LINE}" | grep 200 2>&1 &>/dev/null ; then
                #echo "${LINE} is up"
                sleep 1
        else
                #echo "${LINE} is down"
                 echo "${LINE} is down" | mail -s "Env is down ${LINE}" -a "From:alerts@xyz.one" bob.bok@example.com
sleep 1
        fi
done < env-list.txt
```

When I put this script in cron

```
*/5 * * * * /scripts/check_running/check-running.sh
```

in var/log/mail.log I get

```
Aug 21 13:45:01 dev postfix/pickup[1495499]: 99CC78C1D42: uid=0 from=<root>
Aug 21 13:45:01 dev postfix/cleanup[1500197]: 99CC78C1D42: message-id=<20230821114501.99CC78C1D42@dev.localdomain>
Aug 21 13:45:01 dev postfix/qmgr[1483811]: 99CC78C1D42: from=<root@dev.localdomain>, size=704, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 21 13:45:01 dev postfix/local[1500199]: warning: dict_nis_init: NIS domain name not set - NIS lookups disabled
Aug 21 13:45:01 dev postfix/local[1500199]: 99CC78C1D42: to=<mod@dev.localdomain>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=0.07, delays=0.06/0.01/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Aug 21 13:45:01 dev postfix/qmgr[1483811]: 99CC78C1D42: removed
```

i don't know why when cron run the job , it takes root@dev.localdomain mod@dev.localdomain not this provided in check-running.sh

this is my postfix main.cf

```
# Enable auth
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
header_size_limit = 4096000
relayhost = [mx.xyz.one]:587
inet_interfaces = 127.0.0.1
```

I have tried:
Change this

```
echo "${LINE} is down" | mail -s "Env is down ${LINE}" -a "From:alerts@xyz.one" bob.bok@example.com
```

to this

```
echo "${LINE} is down" | /usr/bin/mail -s "Env is down ${LINE}" -a "From:alerts@xyz.one" bob.bok@example.com
```

and

this

```
*/5 * * * * /scripts/check_running/check-running.sh
```

change to:

```
*/5 * * * * bin/bash /scripts/check_running/check-running.sh
```

Comment: What error do you get? check the mails of the local account that runs the cron

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works  for me.
In script i had to add absolute path for env-list.txt.
In cron above the job I add MAILFROM= and MAILTO=.